# Circular (priority) queue in C

Tags: arrays, c, queue, priority-queue

I have found following code for a circular queue (probably). But I can't understand function `circ_queue_getFirst`. As I see the code initialises struct. Then we can append (not shown) up to 5 elements, first one will be head, last one tail. Why is there `tail` then mentioned, if it should return first member?

```c
typedef struct CircularQueue
{
    uint8_t size;
    
    uint8_t head;

    uint8_t tail;
    
    Data data[5];

} CircularQueue ;
```

```c
void circ_queue_init (CircularQueue *queue){
    queue->head = 0;
    queue->tail = 0;
    queue->size = 5;
}
```

```c
Data circ_queue_getFirst(CircularQueue *queue){
    return queue->data[queue->tail];
}
```

Comment: Look at some of the other functions to see how `head` and `tail` are used. They are just identifiers.

Comment: It is internal implementation design choice, totally transparent to the queue API user (assuming it is implemented properly).